# inform when a job is done at remote machine

Tags: linux

I have two machines: `my` PC on which I work normally (GUI etc) and `remote` PC on which I run some time consuming processes. I would like to know when the currently run job at `remote` finishes.

I have some simple solutions, like checking periodically if the process at `remote` still runs

```
# at my:
ssh remote 'ps aux | grep process' | inform_if_finished
# inform_if_finished pops up a notification at the desktop
```

or pinging `my` machine when the `remote` finishes

```
# at remote:
sh long_job.sh ; ping my
```

and the ping is captured by a simple local daemon...

But all those are rather hacks than real solutions. Is there any standard way to handle such signaling?

Comment: What part do you feel is *hackish*?

Answer (score 2):

if you are ready to invest (read waste :)) your time, you can use a sendmail program to send you a mail when the program is done. Same can be extended to sending a sms on your mobile.

Comment: +1 for sendmail (although I cannot install sendmail at the destination)